# Flash Builder Error Fails to Compile Due to Unexpected '?' character

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I get the following error when attempting to compile an AS3 project:

```
 C:\Users\test\src\LikeText.as:10:Error: Unexpected character. '?' is not allowed here
```

However my code does not have any '?' characters:

```
  public var sleep:uint = 0;  //this is the line causing the error

  public var skip_payload:Boolean = false;

  private var starter:World_word = null;

  public var var_27:uint = 0;
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I've had situations where I'd somehow gotten a control or other unprintable character in the text.  Sometimes fully deleting and retyping the offending line resolves the issue.  Just a thought...